# Problem with context in multisite - getting main site data in every blog (get_pages())

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I'm working on a multisite, everything is configured and works fine from dashboard. 
Now I'm trying to write a plugin with a PHP file that displays the list of pages created in a site - to be displayed to the admin of the site who logs in.

Here is the code (simplified)

```
<?php
require('../../../wp-load.php');
?>
(some HTML)
<?php    
    $pages = get_pages();                                  

    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        echo $page->post_title . '<br>'
?>
```

My plugin PHP file uses `login_redirect` filter to redirect user after login to that PHP file where I am trying to display the list of pages the user created:

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request ) { 
    return '/wp-content/plugins/my-admin-plugin/my-admin-view-all-pages.php'; 
}
```

THE PROBLEM - no matter which site I'm in, I get the list of pages created in the "main" site. How do I pass the context of the existing site to the functions?

Comment: Why do you call `wp-load.php`? That shouldn’t be necessary.

Comment: toscho - how do I get access to WP functions from my own PHP file otherwise?

Comment: [Register an address](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api) and get the WP environment for free. :)

Comment: @toscho just wondering ... is that the right link as the OP was asking about listing the pages in the current site

Comment: @OS is this code what you are looking for? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages and you shouldn't be using wp-load.php

Comment: Damien: (1) without wp-load.php I got errors when trying to access WP functions (2) I use $pages = get_pages(); - it returns the pages of the master network site (blog_id=1), not the sub site the user logged in to

Comment: @OS. Please update your question: Where exactly creates your plugin output?

Comment: toscho - my plugin PHP file uses login_redirect filter to redirect user after login to a PHP file where I am trying to display the list of pages the user created: function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request)
{
  
  return '/wp-content/plugins/my-admin-plugin/my-admin-view-all-pages.php';
}

Comment: OS, you should add new info to the Question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing this is not correct.

Two possibilities:

#### 1) Create a Dashboard Widget to display the information

- For the Network Dashboard, but illustrates well: [How to Display Network Post Count?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/66963/12615)
- Minimal widget:

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_60096_dashboard_widget');

function wpse_60096_dashboard_widget() {
    if( current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
        wp_add_dashboard_widget( 
            'wpse_60096', 
            'Site Pages', 
            'wpse_60096_add_widget_content'
        );
}

function wpse_60096_add_widget_content() {
    $pages = get_pages();                                  
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) 
        echo $page->post_title . '<br>'; 
}
```

#### 2) Register an invisible submenu page

- [Plugin - create a page without it appearing in the side menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/65207/12615)
- Redirect the login to that page: [How to create and link to administration page for a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/4677/12615)