# Count posts by type including drafts and pending posts

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, post-status, count

I had this function that counts posts number by type (taken from wordpress codex)

```
function count_user_posts_by_type($userid, $post_type) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql($post_type, TRUE, $userid);
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->posts} $where" );
    return apply_filters('get_usernumposts', $count, $userid);
}
```

and I changed it in order to display even posts with "draft" and "pending" status.

```
function count_user_posts_by_type($userid, $post_type) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql($post_type, TRUE, $userid);
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) 
                            FROM {$wpdb->posts} $where 
                            AND (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'draft' OR post_status = 'pending')");
    return apply_filters('get_usernumposts', $count, $userid);
}
```

but it doesn't work. If I echo the function like this

```
echo count_user_posts_by_type(wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'percorso');
```

I can see it counts just published posts. What's wrong with what I wrote?
Thanks!

EDIT: as suggested, I performed a var_dump for SELECT COUNT etc. here's what I got

```
string(216) 
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mi_posts 
    WHERE post_author = 1 
    AND post_type = 'percorso' 
    AND (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'private') 
    AND (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'draft' OR post_status = 'pending')"
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Post the generated SQL and see if it works without that `apply_filters` part.

Comment: where can I find the generated sql? what do you mean? Sorry, I'm just a newbie :P
anyway, I tried to delete the 'apply_filters' part but the function doesn't work at all without that piece of code.

Comment: Add `var_dump("SELECT ... post_status = 'pending'");` to your code. If you delete that filter line you have to `return $count`; I am more interested in seeing what the output is than in having a working piece of code, right now.

Comment: Maybe it [can be done](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72899/12615) without `$wpdb`...

Comment: s_ha_dum I edited my original post and added the `var_dump`. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to use `$wpdb`, a simple [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) can handle it. Check [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for the full list of parameters.

```
function count_user_posts_by_type( $userid, $post_type ) 
{
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => $post_type,
        'post_status'   => array( 'publish', 'private', 'draft', 'pending' ),
        'author'        => $userid
    );
    $count_posts = count( get_posts( $args ) ); 
    return $count_posts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks brasofilo! Your function is almost perfect, but it has two little mistakes. I edited it and successfully used it on my blog. Can I edit your post? Or it's better if I add a new answer to the post with the correct version?

Comment: @SheHulk, what mistakes?

Comment: Sorry, I read my question and realized you wrote it like this to exactly display publish, drafts and pending posts as I asked, but when I tryed to use it in my template it didn't work (I don't understand why, I assumed there was a mistake in the function but more likely the mistake was in how I used it :P ). So I changed  `'post_status'   => array( ),` with `post_status'   => $post_status,` and added `$post_status` parameter to the function. Then simply called it different times in the template (count drafts, count published, etc.) and added together the values, when needed.